# Grails - Convert String data to Date

Tags: grails

Lets say, i have a "Book" class with field "availableOn"(as shown below).

```
class Book {
    String availableOn;
}
```

The fields holds values

- "All days" or
- String representation of a date. For example "13/06/2012"

How can i get all Books that are available within next two days? The below code would throw an exception ("java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String")

```
def books = c.list(){
    between('availableOn', new Date(), new Date() + 2)
}
```

PS : Am working on a legacy DB, and so am not suppose to change the schema :(

Comment: i think java cast error is using between on the string 'avaialbleOn' ,field .is that right ?

Comment: We can use "between" for String fields. The problem here is that, am trying to equate that with Date objects.

Comment: so that exception is giving a data value for a string field , i think @zoran119 solution is nice ,if it still doesn't meet you req't please let me know ...

Comment: Yeah. its nice solution. But this application has millions of records, so keeping records in memory is not an option.

Comment: @ashipj Check out [this test](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864913/) supporting my answer.

Comment: @ashipj have a look at my updated answer where I have used `sqlRestriction`. You can try that.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are 2 problems which the `between` statement will have:

- `availableOn` cannot be converted to a `Date` for comparison when its value is `All days`
- Even when `availableOn` has a date value in it, it is not converted to a `Date` for the comparison

I'd try something along the lines of this:

```
def now = new Date()
def books = Book.findAllByAvailableNotEqual("All days").findAll { book ->
    Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', book.availableOn) > now && Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', book.availableOn) < now+2
}
```

Clearly, this can be done in a nicer way (adding some methods to the domain class for example), but this should illustrate my idea...

Comment: this will fetch all objects into memory from DB

Comment: Is there any other way, other than fetching data into memory and then doing a filter. Am getting a feel that, that's the only option.

Comment: maybe dmahapatro's answer could do that, i just think you need to change the date format to something which can work with string comparison (epoch time or 'yyyyDDmmhhMMss' type of a thing)

Comment: Changed format will not match with the format of `availableOn` present in the db.

Comment: @zoran119 You are excluding "All days". Books available every day should be available today, tomorrow and day after. :-)

Comment: @dmahapatro Good point :) The solution is not memory efficient as it is so ashipj might as well just ` + Book.findAllByAvailableOn("All days")` to the result :)

Comment: @dmahapatro What I was I was trying to do with the dates (but did it incorrectly) is to convert the date from the database into something which can be compared as strings... I guess something like this might work: `Date.parse('dd/MM/yyyy', book.availableOn).format('yyyyDDmmhhMMss')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format` on a date to get desired string format of it.

`new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy')`

And your criteria would get modified to

```
def books = c.list(){
    def todayDateStr = new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy')
    def twoDaysAfterTodayDateStr = (new Date()+2).format('dd/MM/yyyy')
    or{
        between('availableOn', todayDateStr, twoDaysAfterTodayDateStr)
        eq 'availableOn', 'All Days'
    }
}
```

Test if the str comparison works, otherwise other ways has to be used. Sending from phone, excuse my typos.

**UPDATE**
The above would fail in peculiar cases when dates are like "01/01/2013" and "07/11/2011".
Alternatively, you can use `sqlRestriction` but in that case it gets tightly coupled with the underlying database. Something like this can be done if Oracle db is used:

```
def books = c.list(){
    def todayDateStr = new Date().format('dd/MM/yyyy')
    def twoDaysAfterTodayDateStr = (new Date()+2).format('dd/MM/yyyy')
    or{
        sqlRestriction "to_date(available_on, 'DD/MM/YYYY') between to_date(todayDateStr, 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date(twoDaysAfterTodayDateStr, 'DD/MM/YYYY')"
        eq 'availableOn', 'All Days'
    }
}
```

Comment: @dmahapatro i don't think this works, the comparison on a string field with a the two date values in the between parameter ,which for between comparing them as a date was impossible,isn't ?

Comment: @danielad It works for me. [I tested it](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864913/) as soon as I got access to my computer. Refer my [test code](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5864913/).

Comment: @JamesKleeh Thanks. What change in date format were you pointing at?

Comment: Since this will be a string comparison "01/01/2013" would come before "05/04/2011" so you have to put the year first, then month, then day: "yyyy/MM/dd". If it requires hours/minutes/seconds then they need to be added in that order as well.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you try with 07/13/2011 or 07/13/2012 as Dates. This would fail. Its just doing a String comparison.

Comment: @JamesKleeh But again "Changed format will not match with the format of `availableOn` present in the db." correct? There should be another way.

Comment: @JamesKleeh `sqlRestriction` can be used to do `between` but again it is tightly coupled to db that is used.

Comment: @dmahapatro Yes that is true if the format of the string on the database isn't `yyyyMMdd` then it won't work. Given that information, I can't see a way of doing this without changing the data in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a criteria based solution, but you can try something like this:

```
Book.executeQuery(
      "select book from Book book where book.availableOn = :availableOn or to_date(book.availableOn, :format) between (:startDate, :endDate) ",
     [availableOn:"All days", format: "dd/MM/yyyy", startDate: startDate, endDate:endDate])
```

The problem with my solution is that this query becomes DB dependent. `to_date` is an Oracle function. You may want to alter this to fit your database

Comment: Thanks Funtik, Unfortunately, i cant try sql or hql queries here. Am suppose to use a custom criteriaBuilder class to create this criteria. This is a design pattern, that we follow.

Comment: bad luck, bro :) I could not find a way how to invoke a custom DB function from the hibernate criteria API. But using a fetch-all-into-memory-and-filter-it-later approach is not an option, IMHO

Comment: Yeah.. fetch-all-into-memory-and-filter-it-later is never an option.